Postfix problems on new RHEL 9.3 install
I'm trying to build a new Postfix mail server to replace an old RHEL 6.3 system. The build has postfix, postfix-mysql, amavisd, dovecot, spamassassin and clamAV installed. The build is not supposed to use MavisDB client but when I go to test the install I get the following from postfix/smtpd in the /var/log/maillog:
warning: connect to mysql server X.X.X.X : Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: /usr/lib64/mariadb/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The file does exist and I'm not sure why it's trying to use Maria when I have the postfix-mysql RPM installed. Is there some flag that I need to use in the main or master.cf files? Or do I have to get an SRPM and do a custom install of postfix?
Thanks in advance for any help.

MariaDB is not MavisDB, those are different products. MariaDB is a drop in replacement for MySQL and it's the default when you want to use MySQL in RHEL9.
